# Redirect url with get variables use .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

It is possible to redirect in .htaccess
this url
http://test.com/uploads/image.jpg?w=200

to this
http://test.com/public/uploads/image/200.jpg

?
I need this to cache system in my rest API.
I'm not sure that is possible rewrite get variable in this way.

Cheers

Comment: Did you try something?

Answer (score 0):

Check this rule, maybe it help.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^uploads/image.jpg
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} w=(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/uploads/image/%1.jpg? [R=301,L]
```